# Redux Angular2 subscription

Tags: angular, redux, observable, reduce, subscription

I try to apply redux to my app but cant subscribe on changes.
**component:**
    import { USER_SIGN_IN } from '../../core/reducers/authorization';
    this.store.dispatch({ type: USER_SIGN_IN,  payload: data: data[0]});

**reducer:**

```
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
export const USER_SIGN_IN = 'USER_SIGN_IN';
export function userSingIn(payload: T) {
    return {
        type: 'USER_SIGN_IN',
        payload: payload
    }
}
```

**service:**

```
this.store.select(state => state.user).subscribe((user)=> {
  console.log('user:', user);
});
```

**app module**

```
StoreModule.provideStore({ user : userSingIn }),

My payload object is empty, i don't understand why

There is console log of subscription:
    Object {type: "USER_SIGN_IN", payload: Object}payload: Objectpayload: Objectpayload: undefinedtype: "USER_SIGN_IN"__proto__: Objecttype: "USER_SIGN_IN"__proto__: Objecttype: "USER_SIGN_IN"__proto__: Object
```

Comment: you didn't `dispatch` anything to your store. So it will be empty only

Comment: @Tanya if you want to get some more detail on redux architecture you can check this link 

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

under adv tab - ngrx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dispatched. 
**component:**

```
this.store.dispatch({ type: USER_SIGN_IN, payload: data: data[0]});
```

The problem was in payload object. The payload object was empty. I added action.payload and everything works now.
**reducer:**

```
export function userSingIn(state, action: Action) {
return {
    type: 'USER_SIGN_IN',
    payload: action.payload
   }
}
```

Comment: The question is answered.